# mailchimp delete issue using php

Tags: php, mailchimp

i want to delete the users from the list in `mailchimp`. i am using `listBatchUnsubscriber()` function with argument like given below.

but that is not working means not deleted and also not unsubscribed the particular users from the list

how can i solve the issue?

i tried like this

```
listBatchUnsubscribe( $listId1, $already_emails, $delete_member=true, $send_goodbye=true, $send_notify=false)
```

Comment: any error return in function? can you display output of function?

Comment: It does'nt displaying any output

Comment: Assign it $unsubscribe_result = listBatchUnsubscribe( $listId1, $already_emails, $delete_member=true, $send_goodbye=true, $send_notify=false); and print  $unsubscribe_result

Comment: Output:Array ( [success_count] => 4 [error_count] => 0 [errors] => Array ( ) )

Comment: That means function is working fine.